# Google Api Error: Invalid request - The caller does not have permission Fastlane React native

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, google-play-services, fastlane

```
default_platform(:android)

def getVersionCode
  thirtySeptemberTwentyTwenty = 1601480940 / 60
  legacyVersionCode = 10902
  versionCode = legacyVersionCode + (Time.now.to_i / 60) - thirtySeptemberTwentyTwenty

  if versionCode > 2100000000
    raise "versionCode cannot be higher than 2100000000"
  end

  versionCode.floor()
end

platform :android do
    desc "Increments internal build number tracking (different than version)"
    lane :bump_build_number do
      android_set_version_code(
        version_code: getVersionCode()
      )
  end

  desc "Build and uploads the app to playstore for a internal testing release"
  lane :playstoreInternal do 
        # Retrieve version of my app in package.json (React Native case)
    package = load_json(json_path: "../package.json")

        # Clean build folder
    gradle(
      task: "clean"
    )

        # Bump android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    bump_build_number

        # Do the bundle of the application
    gradle(
      task: 'bundle',
      build_type: 'Release',
    )

    upload_to_play_store(
      track: 'internal',
      release_status: 'draft',
      skip_upload_apk: true,
      version_name: package["version"]
    )
  end
  
end
```

Using this to deploy app on the store but getting error from google. I have checked google permissions multiple times but not getting why it is coming. Please check it

Error:
[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - The caller does not have permission

Comment: Any success? I have faced the same error recently